# Create multiple forms on the same page

Tags: python, web2py

I am trying to figure out how to create many forms that are similar on one page. The idea is to have people comment on various sections of a page with text. This means that,
each section has its comments. The forms are the same with a comment field and a submit button.
This is the code i got so far. However it does not work and i definitely need to understand how this can be achieved in a simple way. Can somebody help me figure this out.

In model:

```
db.define_table('manyforms',
    Field('comment'))
```

In controller:

```
allforms=dict(form_id=new_form_id(),form=SQLFORM(db.manyforms))
for f in allforms:
    if f['form'].accepts(request.vars,formname=f['form_id']):
        response.flash = 'accepted'
    else: 
        response.flash = 'refused'
return dict(allforms=allforms)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a useful reference: [Multiple forms per page (web2py documentation)](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Multiple-forms-per-page)

Also, in your function, you are iterating through a dict of two items of different types. You are trying to treat each of those objects (one of which will presumably be an integer, the other, a form) as some object that is indexed by a string key (such as a dict).

Finally, it is not clear from your post what you want your function to do. Does your function correspond to a view? If so, do you really want a bunch of forms that are accessed in your view by a single variable {{=allforms}}? Perhaps from an engineering point of view, a better route is to first create a function that generates a list of forms; maybe something like this:

```
def generate_forms():
  form_id_list = # create id list according to whatever criteria
  forms = [SQLFORM(db.manyforms, _id = _id) for _id in form_id_list]

  for form in forms: 
    if form.process(request.vars, formname = form['_id']).accepted:
        response.flash = 'accepted'
    else: 
        response.flash = 'refused'

  return forms
```

Comment: thanks for the pointer. It has finally worked. i wanted the forms to show in different places. Each form just needed a unique id. Your code helps in generating the ids